# MySQL Join for parent record using multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, parent

I've three tables: menu, menu_data, languages . The first one is used to store the menu information that not needs to be localized, the second contains localized data based on language ( like title ) and the last one contains the language IDs. The menu can be owned by a parent and i want to extract this parent when selecting the child menu.
I can do it using a nested LEFT JOIN query like this:

```sql
SELECT la.title, la.permaname, menu.edittime, menu.id, la2.title AS parent_title, pmenu.id AS parent_id 
FROM fm_menu AS menu 
LEFT JOIN fm_menu_data AS la ON ( menu.id = la.targetid and la.languageid = 1 ) 
LEFT JOIN fm_menu AS pmenu ON pmenu.id = menu.parentmenu 
LEFT JOIN fm_menu_data AS la2 ON ( pmenu.id = la2.targetid and la2.languageid = 1 )
```

But, my question is, there a more compact, faster or correct way to do something like this ?

Comment: Looks about right to me.

Comment: Yea, it's right and works fine, but i'm asking if there is a more right or compact way to do the same query

Comment: And that's what I mean, it looks as simple as it can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks good.

You can make it *slightly* more compact by removing the unnecessary brackets from your join conditions and removing the optional `AS` keywords.

This is the same, but expressed in less characters:

```
SELECT la.title, la.permaname, menu.edittime, menu.id, la2.title AS parent_title, pmenu.id AS parent_id 
FROM fm_menu AS menu 
LEFT JOIN fm_menu_data la ON menu.id = la.targetid and la.languageid = 1
LEFT JOIN fm_menu pmenu ON pmenu.id = menu.parentmenu 
LEFT JOIN fm_menu_data la2 ON pmenu.id = la2.targetid and la2.languageid = 1
```